# New variable from list.file

Tags: r, csv, lapply

I am creating an object calling all `.csv` files in a directory, reading them in according to some specifications, and merging them.

Before merging them I want to take the first two letters of the file names and create a new column in each table reporting that two letter as a variable.

I got this far:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, function(x) read.csv(x,
                                        header=TRUE, 
                                        #sep=";",
                                        stringsAsFactors=F,
                                        encoding = "UTF-8",
                                        na.strings = c("NA",""),
                                        colClasses=c("code"="character")))

myfiles.final = do.call(rbind, myfiles)
```

When I try to create the new variable though I generate a replacement that has double the rows of the data:

```
temp.2 <- lapply(temp, function(x) substr(x, start = 1, stop = 2))
myfiles.2 = lapply(myfiles, 
               function(x){
                 a <- temp.2[seq_along(myfiles)]
                 x$identifier <- rep(a,nrow(x))
                 return(x)
                 })
```

In the folder the files are named, for example `AA029893.csv`,`BB024593.csv`..., for the first table I just want a new column called "identifier" that has "AA" for all entries, for the second "BB", and so on.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply` is good for iterating along 1 list (e.g., `myfiles` data frames). To add a column to each data frame, you want to iterate in parallel over two lists, the list of data frames and the list of names. `Map` does this (for an arbitrary number of lists):

```
myfiles.2 = Map(function(dd, nn) {dd$identifier = nn; return(dd)},
                dd = myfiles, nn = temp.2)
```

An easier alternative is to add the column post-hoc:

```
myfiles.final = do.call(rbind, myfiles)
myfiles.final$identifier = rep(
  sapply(temp, function(x) substr(x, start = 1, stop = 2)),
  each = lengths(myfiles)
)
```

The easiest alternative is to use `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows`, either of which will automatically add an `ID` column based on the names of your list. Depending on the size of your data, they might be quite a bit faster as well.

```
names(myfiles) = sapply(temp, function(x) substr(x, start = 1, stop = 2))
myfiles.2 = dplyr::bind_rows(myfiles)
myfiles.2 = data.table::rbindlist(myfiles, idcol = "identifier")
```